# Use of triple pointer over double pointer when only reading value of double pointer?

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers, double-pointer

This code only looks like this as the use of structs and global variables is prohibited in the assignment.

It works either way, but I was wondering whether only using a double pointer would reallocate a temporary copy of the pointer.

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

void allocateData(char ***dptrArrayData, int *intArraySize)
{
    *dptrArrayData = (char**)malloc(*intArraySize*sizeof(char*));
    for (int i = 0; i < *intArraySize; i++)
    {
        (*dptrArrayData)[i] = (char*)malloc(12*sizeof(char));
        (*dptrArrayData)[i] = "Lorem Ipsum";
    }
}

void printDataDoublePointer(char **dptrArrayData, int intArraySize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < intArraySize; i++)
    {
        printf("Text:%s at index:%d\n",dptrArrayData[i],i);
    }
}

void printDataTriplePointer(char ***dptrArrayData, int *intArraySize)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < *intArraySize; i++)
    {
        printf("Text:%s at index:%d\n",(*dptrArrayData)[i],i);
    }
}
int main()
{
    char **dptrArrayData;
    int intArraySize = 5;
    allocateData(&dptrArrayData,&intArraySize);
    printDataDoublePointer(dptrArrayData,intArraySize);
    printDataTriplePointer(&dptrArrayData,&intArraySize);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The function parameter needs to have one more `*` than the variable that it's updating.

Comment: You could use a `char **` return value instead of `char ***` parameter.

Comment: The question isnt about updating, and sadly I cannot use a return value as I will return many arrays in one function, the question is whether using the double pointer to only read is the same as using a triple pointer.

Comment: What is it about? `allocateData()` needs to update the variable `dptrArrayData`, so it needs `char ***`. The other functions don't update anything, so they can use `char **`.

Comment: So when I pass in the double pointer only it doesnt create a temporary copy of the array to read from? Because if I update something in the double pointer one the value stays in scope. Edit: I am a noob at c, oop is all I know...

Comment: (*dptrArrayData)[i] = (char*)malloc(12*sizeof(char));
        (*dptrArrayData)[i] = "Lorem Ipsum";
This is nonsense.

Comment: I put it as an example, but this is how you allocate a dynamic 2D char array if you have a triple pointer passed, am I wrong? The assignment of the value is only as a test.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> It works either way, but I was wondering whether only using a double pointer would reallocate a temporary copy of the pointer.

I take you to be asking about the difference between

> ```
> void printDataDoublePointer(char **dptrArrayData, int intArraySize)
> ```

and

> ```
> void printDataTriplePointer(char ***dptrArrayData, int *intArraySize)
> ```

.  In each case the function receives copies of all argument values presented by the caller.  This is the essence of pass-by-value semantics, which are the only function-call semantics C provides.

But there is no reallocation involved.  When a pointer is passed as a function argument, only the pointer is copied, not the object to which it points.  The function receives an independent pointer to the same object the original points to.

Comment: Thank you, I didnt  know that, maybe they should tell us this at school lol

Comment: It's right there in the name: "pointer". It's just something that points to something else, not the thing itself.